# Can reapers attack buildings when they are in bunkers?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've never been able to build a bunker next to a hostile building to see if this works.

Comment: Surely they can attack; I imagine the question is whether they use their special attack with bonus damage vs. buildings. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can see it happening here

Comment: Game starting around 5:30.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reapers can attack buildings outside of bunkers. Bunkers only add protection to units inside them. Any units inside bunkers are allowed to attack anything they usually would be able to in-range.